# How to read the chosen or written data from gui and convert it into an object

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, data-binding

I've never worked with gui before and trying to understand how things are going.

I want to make a small program that presents a user table of clients:

Client Name(string) | Client Age(int) | Gender(choose from options) | Student? (bool) |

I want to be able to change values and then press a button "SAVE" - that will convert it to a list of clients, where each client is a class containing: name, age, gender and student.

I want to work with C# and saw that I can use windows forms or WPF. I googled a little and saw that there is mvvm data binding , but I found it a little confusing.

Can you please recommand how and where should I start? If I choose to work with windows forms, how can I do this bind? Whould you recommand working with WPF?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I never did Windows Forms. I started right with WPF. When I make a WPF application I always use the MVVM pattern and also using  the MVVM Light Toolkit. Using this toolkit really helped me to understand MVVM pattern in WPF and made some things easier for me. I would suggest for you to use this http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/! When I started, I used this tutorial for MVVM pattern: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel. Also this tutorial is almost the same as your described example, Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will start reading it :)

Comment: Oh i forget to mention this tutorial uses sql/entityframework. Please ignore this in your case! It is not necessary!

Comment: Did my link helped you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much